# Сохранение пароля И вход в систему

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

К примеру, человек уже зарегистрировался в системе. Мне нужно, чтобы при последующих входах он мог просто нажать Далее и потом войти по своему логину и паролю, с которыми регистрировался ранее. Но сейчас приходится регистрироваться заново. Все данные записываются в txt файл.
Как можно это реализовать?

Код:

```
import pickle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
window.title("user")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window["bg"] = "#141212"
window.iconbitmap("C:\\icons\\user.ico")

def exit():
    window.destroy()

def information():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    if information:
        print(information, end="-пароль   ")
    else:
        print("Пароль не был введён")

def infname():
    information = entryname.get()
    if information:
        print(information, end="-имя")
    else:
        print("Имя не было введено")
              
def check():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    information1 = entryname.get()
    if information.get():
        pass

def recordpassword():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    information1 = entryname.get()
    
    recordfile = open("C:\\sublime,pycharm.i.t.d\\passwords and names.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8")
    recordfile.write("password - ")
    recordfile.write(information)
    recordfile.close()

def recordname():
    information = entrypassword.get()
    information1 = entryname.get()
    recordfile = open("C:\\sublime,pycharm.i.t.d\\passwords and names.txt", "a", encoding = "utf-8")
    recordfile.write(" name - ")
    recordfile.write(information1)
    recordfile.close()


def new_window():
    def third_window():
        third_window = tk.Toplevel(new_window)
        third_window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
        third_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        title = "title"
        third_window.title(title)
    window.withdraw()
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
    new_window.geometry(f"700x300+500+300")
    new_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    new_window.title("user1")
    new_window["bg"] = "#141212"
    new_window.iconbitmap("C:\\icons\\user.ico")
    new_window.protocol("delete", lambda: window.destroy())
    vaa = tk.StringVar(new_window)
    vaa.set(0)




    
    entrypassword = tk.Entry(new_window)
    textpassword = tk.Label(new_window, text="Введите пароль: ", font="Arial 12", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
    entryname = tk.Entry(new_window)
    textname = tk.Label(new_window,text="Введите имя: ", font = "Arial 12", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
    entrypassword.place(x=135, y=28)
    entryname.place(x=108, y=4)
    textpassword.place(x=1, y=25)
    textname.place(x=1, y=1)
    
            
    def log_pass():
        f = open("login.txt", "rb")
        a = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        if entryname.get() in a:
            if entrypassword.get() == a[entryname.get()]:
                third_window()
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Неправильно введены логин или пароль")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Неправильно введен логин или пароль")    
       
       
    continue1 = tk.Button(new_window, text="Войти в систему", command=lambda: log_pass())
    continue1.place(x=1, y=60)
 

def save():
    login_pass_save = {}
    login_pass_save[entryname.get()] = entrypassword.get()
    f = open("login.txt", "wb")
    pickle.dump(login_pass_save, f)
    f.close
    new_window()


    
new_window_button = tk.Button(window, text="Далее", command=save, activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")         
exitbutton = tk.Button(window, text="exit", command=exit, activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
entrypassword = tk.Entry(window)
textpassword = tk.Label(window, text="Введите пароль: ", font="Arial 12", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
entryname = tk.Entry(window)
textname = tk.Label(window,text="Введите имя: ", font = "Arial 12", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
infbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Сохранить", command=lambda:[information(), infname()], activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")
recordbutton = tk.Button(window, text="Записать данные", command=lambda:[recordpassword(), recordname()], activebackground="#7a6d6d", bg = "#141212", fg = "#ffffff")


new_window_button.place(x=2, y=75)
exitbutton.place(x=2, y=273)
recordbutton.place(x=70, y= 50)
infbutton.place(x=2, y=50)
entrypassword.place(x=132, y=28)
entryname.place(x=108, y=4)
textpassword.place(x=1, y=25)
textname.place(x=1, y=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1 - в целом, хранение пароля пользователя - так себе идея. 2 - при старте приложения открываете файл, где хранится пароль, читаете его оттуда, заполняете в поле ввода. Если файла нет или пароль туда не записан - не заполняете. При успешном логине сохряняете пароль в файл.

Comment: если каждый раз нужно логиниться, то лучше храните хеш пароля а не сам пароль. https://habr.com/ru/post/210760/